# Convert String in Expression to Integer

Tags: replacement, expression-manipulation, rule

I have reviewed many string replacement Q&A but I have been unable to apply them to this case (MWE):

```
three = 3^"1";
FullForm[three]
2 three
three /. String -> Integer;
2 three
Replace[three, n : NumberString :> ToExpression[n], All];
FullForm[2 three]

(* Power[3,"1"]
2 3^(1)
2 3^(1)
Times[2,Power[3,"1"]] *)
```

So we see that each replacement actually leaves the String untouched.

The documentation on ReplaceAll etc. is however explicit that one can replace heads; String is a Head; why can it not be replace like Sin?

```
In[1]:= Sin[x]/.Sin->Cos
Out[1]= Cos[x]
```

Why can I not convert a string to an integer in this way, and how would I convert "three" above? (the expression I am interested in fixing up is of course a bit longer than this)

**EDIT**

The actual expression of interest is the output of

```
FullForm[thwPoly[m17]]
```

which is

```
Times[Plus[Times[128,Power[3,"0"]],Times[64,Power[3,"1"]],Times[32,Power[3,"2"]],Times[8,Power[3,"3"]],Times[4,Power[3,"4"]],Times[2,Power[3,"5"]],Power[3,"6"]],Power[Plus[Power[2,"11"],Times[-1,Power[3,"7"]]],-1]]
```

The next attempt:

```
ToExpression/@thwPoly[m17]
```

gives: ToExpression::notstrbox: 128 3^(0)+64 3^(1)+32 3^(2)+8 3^(3)+4 3^(4)+2 3^(5)+3^(6) is not a string or a box. ToExpression can only interpret strings or boxes as Wolfram Language input.

Attending to the need to consider levels of application of Map, I then also tried

```
Map[ToExpression, thwPoly[m17], Infinity]
```

which gave: ToExpression::esntx: Could not parse -(1/139) as input, which is interesting as that is a calculated intermediate result/.

*Success* 
Using

```
Replace[thwPoly[m17], n_String :> FromDigits[n], All]
```

gives -17, the correct value.

So, the conversion has been achieved - but I'm still not clear why head replacement doesn't work.

Comment: Note that after evaluation the form `three = 3^"1"` does not have head `String`.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - yes, which is itself confusing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Replace[ 2 three, n_String :> FromDigits[n], All]
```

> 6

Comment: I could have sworn I also tried that, but am pleased that working explicitly from your example it does indeed work!